# Undefined function static_path/2 in <script> tag

Tags: html, phoenix-framework, elixir

I am using Embedded Elixir for templated HTML.

```
<script src="<%= static_path(@conn, '../js/app.js') %>"> </script>
```

This line is giving me the following error:

```
== Compilation error in file lib/chat_web/views/layout_view.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/chat_web/templates/layout/app.html.eex:24: undefined function static_path/2
(elixir 1.10.2) src/elixir_locals.erl:114: anonymous fn/3 in : 
:elixir_locals.ensure_no_undefined_local/3
(stdlib 3.12.1) erl_eval.erl:680: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
(elixir 1.10.2) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:304: anonymous fn/4 in 
Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_workers/7
```

Comment: how about `Routes.static_path(...)`?

Comment: Do you have `Plug.Static` referenced in your `endpoint.ex`?

Comment: @sbacaro 's answer solved the issue. I was referring to old code base which had just static_path(). Could you tell me when this change occured

Comment: I've added an answer with the same solution I commented before explaining when the change happened

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `static_path` function comes from `YourAppWeb.Router.Helpers` (before Phoenix 1.4, it came from `YourApp.Router.Helpers`), but the important thing is that before 1.4, views would `import YourApp.Router.Helpers`, thus making it available in your views and templates, but from 1.4 onwards, views `alias YourAppWeb.Router.Helpers, as: Routes` (you can verify this in your apps' `web.ex` file), therefore you can access the helper functions using `Routes.<function>`.

so, as suggested in my comment, your example should work with:

```rb
<script src="<%= Routes.static_path(@conn, '../js/app.js') %>"> </script>
```